# Android Camera in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camera2

how i can calculate camera megapixels(wide lens,ultra wide lens,micro etc.) in android studio kotlin

```
val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList.first()
val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
val streamConfigMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)

val imageWidth = streamConfigMap!!.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture::class.java)[0].width
val imageHeight = streamConfigMap.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture::class.java)[0].height
val megapixels = calculateMegapixels(imageWidth, imageHeight)
```

---

```
fun calculateMegapixels(width: Int, height: Int): Int {
    return width * height / 1000000
}
```

but the result is not accurate accourding to device camera specification